# Scala IDE Eclipse release freezes for 2.5 minutes on file save

Tags: eclipse, scala-ide

Whenever I am saving a Scala file within my up-to-date Scala IDE, I have to look at a *Not Responding* Eclipse for 2.5 minutes. Any suggestions, similar problems?

Edit:

> Build id: 3.0.2-vfinal-20131028-1923-Typesafe
>
> Eclipse Standard/SDK Version: 4.3.0

Comment: Which version exactly of Scala IDE? There was a compiler problem some time ago when type inference could take a long time to resolve some specific type inference.

Comment: I added this information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are just running out of memory. You should enable the heap indicator, in `Window > Preferences > General`, check `Show heap status`. An indicator appears in the bottom right corner of the window.

If it looks like most of the memory is used and that the garbage collector is running all the time, increase the memory limit for the VM (-Xmx parameter, there are different ways to do it depending on your install and your OS). We recommend to set this limit to at least 1G, to be on the safe side.

Comment: Is it a problem with every Scala files, or only some? Can you share some of your code?

Comment: It seems that the bigger they become the slower it is. Wildcard imports seem to slow it down, too.